# Category Quick View Popup

Tags: category, ce-1.9.0.1

Can anyone pls let me how to make a quick look popup for Categories just like we do for products ?

I want to display all the sub-categories listing in a popup when clicked on any parent category having child categories

Is it possible ?

Any custom code / extensions are welcome

Comment: Hi Mark, did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes Sander, I resolved the issue and working good.

Comment: Be sure to close this question. If you found another solution please add it as answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the child category ID's from which you can retrieve a collection of categories to display. Just a small warning; performance wise this might not be too good.

Per parent category you can do something like this

```
$children = $category->getChildren(); // returns comma separated child ids
$child_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => explode(',', $children))))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('...'); //whatever else you need

?>
<ul class="category_popup" style="display:none;">
<?php
foreach ($child_collection as $item):
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $item->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $item->getName();?></a></li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

Now all you need is a small Javascript to display the popup. There's not really a standard functionality for that in Magento so you can go with Prototype, jQuery or which ever you prefer.

Comment: How it could affect performance ?

Comment: Because you are retrieving multiple collections which requires queries. As long as it's cached properly you should be ok tho